# Can't push to private repository

Tags: git, git-push, private-repository

By mistake i pushed .env file to github and then i wanted to hide .env file from my private github repo using .gitignore. For this purpose, i did many stupid things and now it's saying repository not found. Please help me fix this!
Now when i do **git push**, it shows -

```
fatal: The current branch master has no upstream branch.`enter code here`
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use
    git push --set-upstream origin master
```

And if i do **git push --set-upstream origin master**, it gives me this error -

```
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Comment: Did you accidentally delete and recreated the `.git` folder? Maybe the remote `origin` has become misconfigured. Check the output of `git remote -v` and check the URLs. What about other git operations, like `git fetch`?

Comment: Yes i mistakenly removed **.git** folder by **rm -rf .git** command. Now what can i do? I ran **git remote -v** and it shows -  origin  git@github.com:Arif-Islam/warehouse-management-server-side-Arif-Islam.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:Arif-Islam/warehouse-management-server-side-Arif-Islam.git (push) @Gino Mempin

Comment: I ran `git remote add origin git@github.com:Arif-Islam/warehouse-management-server-side-Arif-Islam.git` and it shows me that - `error: remote origin already exists.`

Answer (score 2):

A sensible course of action in your case is:

- rename your existing local repository folder

  ```
    cd /path/to/repo
    mv warehouse-management-server-side-Arif-Islam warehouse-management-server-side-Arif-Islam.ori
  ```
- clone the remote GitHub repository again

  ```
    git clone git@github.com:Arif-Islam/warehouse-management-server-side-Arif-Islam.git
  ```
- Delete the file incorrectly pushed, but keep it on the disk

  ```
    git rm --cached -- .env
  ```
- Update your .gitignore

  ```
    echo .env >> .gitignore
  ```
- Add, commit and push

  ```
    git add .
    git commit -m "Delete then ignore .env"
    git push
  ```